# Does anyone know how to fix this build tools version error?

Tags: java, android, build, version

I keep getting this error Using 1.7 requires using Android Build Tools version 19 or later; currently using 17.0.0 but in my manifest file, I have the target sdk version set to 19?
Current sdk file:https://i.stack.imgur.com/odcom.jpg.
None of my files are showing the x mark(for error), only the project itself. I tried cleaning it but my R file wont reload as a result of this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build tools are completely separate from your compile/target SDK version.

In your `build.gradle` file, you should see a `buildToolsVersion` line - change that to a version greater than 19 (the most recent as of this time is `20.0.0`).